# Modificar un campo de todos los documentos

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Saludos, tengo una duda acerca sobre el método update.

```
TablaPTC.update({compGasto:"si"},{$set: {acumulado: "0"}});
```

Actualmente esta así mi método, y no estoy seguro que debo cambiar para que sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Modifique mi método update así:

```
TablaPTC.update({},{$set:{acumulado: 0}},{multi: true},function(err,result){
            if(err){console.log(err)}
        })
```

Añadiendo la parte de : `,{multi: true}, function(err,result){
            if(err){console.log(err)}
        })` 
empezó a funcionar.